Applying remove_action on form in wordpress header Astra
I have a Wordpress website with an Astra child theme.
Astra is generating a search form in my header (so on the whole post and pages).
The form is generated 4x by Astra, and as the method="get".
I don't use this form, and there is nothing in the header custom that ask it to be generated...
I am not able to figure out how to stop astra_get_search_form to generate on the header, in a PHP way.
I was able to remove from html, using jquery:
/* REMOVE form get */
    $(".ast-search-box.header-cover").remove();

But I would prefer to remove using php, directly at the source.
Here is the function for the astra_get_search_form: https://developers.wpastra.com/astra-theme/reference/functions/astra_get_search_form/
I found these articles that explain how to remove the whole header:

https://wpastra.com/docs/remove-astra-header-from-entire-site/
https://developers.wpastra.com/astra-theme/reference/classes/astra_builder_header/global_astra_header/

But still could not apply it for this search form.
Thanks in advance for your help.
-- Edit --
So far the best solution I found was to edit the header.php, by:

Remove all the header calls
Copy the header html generated by Astra
Remove the unnecessary html form

But it is not the right way to process... Any better this way, for safety and SEO.

you cannot change that in the back office, Appearance > Customise > Header builder ?

Hello, not anymore with the last astra version

try in Astra > Dashboard > Header Builder

I tried, this is the same, there is no search show anymore. It is a widget now. But astra still generate it
